# Inserting text into existing textboxes, like an array

Tags: c#

I am reading values from a serial port and would like to place these values in various textboxes on my form.

The textboxes are called:

```
tbMasterParam0, 
tbMasterParam1, 
tbMasterParam2,
...
tbMasterParam15
```

I would like to use the fact that they have a numeric naming structure and call them like they were arrays. Is this possible?

I have attached the code to give some context.

Otherwise I am just running a switch/case but this is becoming quite bulky.  Surely I can do this in a few lines.

```
    private void displayBoardValue(byte[] BoardParameters)
    {
        uint measurement;
        string value;
        measurement = (uint)(BoardParameters[3] + (BoardParameters[2] << 8));
        value = measurement.ToString();

        this.Controls[("tbMasterParam" + boardManager.parameter_id)].Text = value;
    }
```

I seem to be getting a null reference exception

Comment: at which place you are calling it?

Comment: Open your Form.designer.cs and take a look at what the names of these textboxes really are. E.g. `this.tbMasterParam1.Name = "textBox1";` - this name will be the key of the control in the `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather *extract a method*:

```
public TextBox FindTextBox(int index) 
{
     // Find corresponding TextBox here 
     // Note .Find(..., true) - scan not only controls on the form, 
     // but all the child panels, groupboxes etc.
     return Controls.Find("tbMasterParam" + index.ToString(), true).First() as TextBox;
}

...

private void displayBoardValue(byte[] BoardParameters)
{
    uint measurement;
    string value;
    measurement = (uint)(BoardParameters[3] + (BoardParameters[2] << 8));
    value = measurement.ToString();

    FindTextBox(boardManager.parameter_id).Text = value;
}
```

**Edit**: as far as I can see from the comments, the problem is to scan not only *form itself*, but *child* panels, group boxes etc. In that case, you need `Controls.Find(, true)`.

Comment: @Dmytro Shevchenko: all the `TextBox`es (i.e. `tbMasterParam0..tbMasterParam15`) are supposed to exist. If not, better have an exception *thrown* then *swallowed*.

Comment: I am failing to see how your code addresses the exceptions, either.

Comment: If no controls with required name are found, `First()` will throw `InvalidOperation` exception with the message `"Sequence contains no elements"`

Comment: And in the @JonathanBrown's code, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown instead. Which is the actual problem he is trying to solve. He cannot get the controls he needs. And your code does not solve his problem.

Comment: I have tried it like this, however now i am getting an invalid operation exception when the function is called

Comment: @Jonathan Brown: looks like you want `Find(, true)` - see my edit - to scan not ther form itself, but its *child containers* (panels, group boxes) as well.

Comment: Thank You! this seems to work, however, it fills all the text boxes one time round then fails...  Throwing an invalid operation again

Comment: @Jonathan Brown: is it possible, that `parameter_id` is actually beyond `0..15` range? Looks like at the *second* round `parameter_id` is `16` and there's no such a TextBox

Comment: I'm the 'index' is cycling 0 through to 15 the resets and repeats

Comment: @Jonathan Brown: to test if `boardManager.parameter_id` can be without `0..15` range try, please, `FindTextBox(boardManager.parameter_id % 16).Text = value;`

Comment: Yes thank you very much!!   It is a global variable and the conditional statement allows it to reach 16 before being reset.  I have a check running now before the function is called.

Comment: You have been very helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89884/discussion-between-dmitry-bychenko-and-jonathan-brown).

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you can achieve this by using the `Find` method.
Like this:
`this.Controls.Find()`

You might need to cast it to a `TextBox`.